# how can I activate modules and themes?

Tags: 7, theming, installation

I am very new to drupal, so, sorry for my basic question. I have tried to instal new modules and themes. The installation process went OK, I got a"successfully installed" message. But when I want to activate the new module, it does not show up on the HOME / ADMINISTRATION / MODULES list.
The Update Manager module is activated, I am logged on as an administrator, I have all the rights set, but I still cannot see the newly installed modules or themes.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks. Greg

Answer (score 2):

You can enable your installed modules here.

`/admin/modules`

and your theme here

`/admin/appearance`

You can double check to make sure the modules & theme are really there by navigating to your site modules & themes folder.

`/sites/all/modules`
`/sites/all/themes`

Comment: Also very important to check if you have public read access to the folder and files.